# how i can parse data from facebook using graphAPI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm filling it with correct informations.Why it tells me your app id is not valid ???

app secret in here i fake but its true in script. tell me what should i do please

```
      <?php
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

// start session

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '425591634259397','5e5789c1b17394a42c4595dssfa8b4591d0' );

$session = new FacebookSession('425591634259397|5e5789c1b1739dds4a42c4595fa8b4591d0');
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
    // graph api request for user data
    $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/972293049466394/feed' );

    $response = $request->execute();
    // get response
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    // print data
    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
} else {
    // show login url
    echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: your question is way too broad for stackoverflow. please show some effort to find out how the graph api works on your own and feel free to ask when you got stuck: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: Hey I want to know how i can get access token for getting data from a page.

Comment: that´s explained very well in the facebook docs

Comment: hey i want to know is there just 1 access token for getting data from a page. because with page access token i can become a full admin. and that page is not mine. i want to just get data automatically from a page. not add post offline :D

Comment: if that is really your app secret in there, you should remove it. it´s called secret for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "App Access Token" is good enough for reading a Page Feed. With PHP:

```
$accessToken = APP-ID . '|' . APP-SECRET;
```

Example code and information about the Page feed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed

Information about all Access Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

And another link about Access Tokens: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: hey i want ti know how i can get a app access token i cant understand anything from there

Comment: that´s in my answer. it´s just "app id", then a pipe sign, then the "app secret".

Comment: sorry. i cant understand. could you show me an example

Comment: the example is right there in my answer. not sure how to be more detailed, to be honest.

Comment: i test it. it returns me an error : www.tgco.org/parser/facebook.php

Comment: "Invalid application ID" - fix it then

Comment: btw, you don´t even need to set the app token on your own, afaik that´s what "setDefaultApplication" does anyway. so just make sure to use the correct data.